# Using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore is working when adding package but stops working when running the project

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity

Using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore is working when adding a package but stops working when running the project. How I can solve this?

Now it's working:

[image]

When I run the project file, it stops working. Again when I build that file, it works again:

[image]

Here are my csproj files:

[image]

I tried to use SQLite 5.0.1 and design 5.0.1 but they didn't make any change.

Sorry for my bad English :) I hope you can help me.

Comment: Do not paste screenshots. Copy your code and write it. This way will be more proper to get an answer.

Comment: According to the screenshot, your solution contains multiple projects, please check these projects' target framework version and make sure they have installed the correct EF core package version. Besides, it seems that the "royaljanzfinal.data" project is a class library, after updating the class library, please rebuild the project, and re-add the class library reference in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your target framework is `netstandard2.1`. But you are trying to use EntityFrameworkCore 3.1. You can try to upgrade your target framework to 3.1 as follows:

```
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

You can read more from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: In my startup-project file, my target framework is netcoreapp3.1 as you mentioned. This folder is a classlib.

Comment: Ok then in here, you won't use EntityFrameworkCore. You can change it with the following one:

 <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />